# Visual Studio не видит референсы после смены директории проекта

Tags: visual-studio

До:

```
/../solution.sln
/../packages/../
/../projectName/project.csproj + все файлы проекта
```

После:

```
/../solution.sln
/../packages/../
/../project.csproj + все файлы проекта
```

Всё, что мне нужно это перенести проект и все файлы проекта на директорию выше, к решению. После переноса ни один неймспейс не распознаётся, а при сборке выходит ошибка:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
> computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.

Из того, что пробовал:

- `dotnet restore` через CMD (никаких ошибок)
- `Update-Package -Reinstall` (всё успешно переустановилось, но не помогло)
- удалял все референсы NuGet в файле проекта
- заменил все `..\packages` на `..\..\packages` в файле проекта, как посоветовали [здесь](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/moving-project-folders/1048247)

Comment: Удаление блока Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" из файла проекта позволяет собрать проект, но это, как я понял, отключает варны при отсутствии пакетов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замена всех `..\packages` на `packages` в файле проекта решило проблему. После я ещё обновлял несколько пакетов и у меня в блоке `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">` была указана старая версия одного пакета, исправил на актуальную и всё собралось.